# Replacement for Spring-EncryptionUtils in Spring 3.1

Tags: java, spring, security, encryption

I migrated a project to Spring 3.1 that used the

```
org.springframework.security.util.EncryptionUtils
```

This class seems to be gone in Spring 3.1 and I found some reference that it had already been depracated in Spring 3.0.

The Utilities haven been used for a simple synchronous encryption:

```
encryptedText = EncryptionUtils.encrypt(password, text)
decryptedText = EncryptionUtils.decrypt(password, encryptedText)
```

This was a nice and simple approach. Can you advise for a good substitute to use that allows to achieve the same results?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following utility

```
org.acegisecurity.util.EncryptionUtils
```

You can download this using below URL

```
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadacegisecurity107osgijar.htm
```

This class is useful if you have simple needs and wish to use the DESede encryption cipher.

But for more sophisticated requirements will need to use the Java crypto libraries directly.

Comment: I dont have `org.acegisecurity.util.EncryptionUtils` in my classpath, since I migrated to Spring 3.1.

Comment: You have to download this library. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadacegisecurity107osgijar.htm

Comment: The `deprecated` note in the JavaDoc for `EncryptionUtils` suggests that you utilize a dedicated encryption library, meaning you will likely need to download something if it is not already a part of Java.